# Improve error when uploading an image with the wrong extension

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader

Yesterday I was trying to rescue a broken image with help of the Wayback Machine. When I tried to upload it, I got a generic error message:

> Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server

In my browser console, I see the following:

> {
> "Success": false,
> "Error": 5,
> "ErrorMessage": "Failed to upload image; an error occurred on the server"
> }

It turned out that it was a [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) image with extension `.png`. From the screenshot below, you can see it makes sense as a PNG, and while the image was hotlinked, our browsers had no problem displaying it.

---

[image: screenshot of uploader with error message]

Comment: You totally changed the question, but guess that's legit as no answers were posted. Anyway, I'm afraid that's something 100% on imgur side, nothing SE can do except ask them to change it, and I'm pretty sure they'll gracefully ignore any such request. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Well, that's not actually true. For this specific issue, the in-page JavaScript could test the filename for one of the permitted extensions. Doing so does, however, increase complexity and carry potential future dependencies. A) It's another part of the code that has to be included everywhere there's an upload (at least 4 variations). B) The allowed extensions might be different between different upload destinations (which do exist; e.g. Teams). C) If the upload destination or list of file types are changed, then this code would have to change too. D) etc.

Comment: It is possible to also change the .WebP to a .png or .jpg. For example, https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg and https://cloudconvert.com/jpg-converter both change .WebP to .jpg. The .png also applies to both sites. Although this is an extra step to uploading.